# Typescript: How to correctly type response.data on front-end side based on success of the request?

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios

Consider this context: An API auth route which I don't have access to view or edit the code returns

```js
interface AuthSuccess {
  token: string
  user: object
}
```

on response.data if email and password are correct, but returns

```js
interface AuthError {
  error: string
}
```

on error.response.data if they aren't correct or aren't passed in the body.

On my front-end, built in NextJS with axios to make requests, I've created the following function to call this route:

```js
const auth = ({email, password}) =>
  api // api is the return of axios.create()
    .post(url, {email, password})
    .then((result) => ({
      success: true,
      data: response.data // here it it AuthSuccess
    }))
    .catch((error) => ({
      success: false,
      data: error.response?.data // here it is AuthError
    }))
```

However, when I call this function like this

```js
const res = await auth(data)

if (res.success) {
  // here I expect data to be AuthSuccess type
} else {
  // here I expect data to be AuthError type
}
```

Even if I'm verifying `res.success`, inside the if block Typescript acts like data can have both types, which it can't, obviously.

I've tried 2 solutions so far:

1. Setting `auth` type as `(arg: AuthProps): Promise<AuthSuccess | AuthError>`, which creates the problem with the if block
2. Creating another type, conditionally:

```js
interface AuthResult<T extends boolean> {
  success: T
  data: T extends true ? AuthSuccess : AuthError
}
```

And setting `auth` to be `(arg: AuthProps): Promise<AuthResult>`, to which TS complains about not passing the generic, and at the if block everything becomes `any`.

So, how can I type this function correctly? Or how can I refactor it to stop the problem? Ty in advance

Comment: For the success response you can use `.then((result: AxiosResponse<AuthSuccess>)` there may be something similar for the error though I don't know it

Comment: You would have to return a union type and [discriminate it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) - `{ success: true, data: AuthSuccess } | { success: false, data: AuthError }`. Maybe resolving with `AuthSuccess` or rejecting with `AuthError` is a better interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a **union type**:

```
interface SuccessResponse {
  success: true;
  data: {
    token: string;
    user: object;
  };
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  success: false;
  data: {
    error: string;
  };
}

type AuthResponse = SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse;

const test = (res: AuthResponse) => {
  if (res.success) {
    return res.data; // { token: string; user: object; }
  } else {
    return res.data; // { error: string; }
  }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcFIM7YEoTYAOA9iNigN4BQyy2mO2AXMmFOhANy3IAmcMHFY06dMCQDWEEK2ztQAcx5jk6ClFYkARgCsICMCuQBfHierVQkWIhQBRKFBJQCxMhWSj6jQi2TwADYUxgJCIrx00M6a9Aogyrxm1BbUYACeRCgAguhgABZupOQoALxovrhFHigAPsiOMdUlPNQIHmBshJ3lABRQhKy5Bc0UAJTIpQB8XrzAMMj9hAB0DFh+E950A2DoUCDIA9jLYXDGJsgQwVSRhxC7+3fHp+cp1EA)

---

Or a **function that returns a type predicate**:

```
interface SuccessResponse {
  success: true;
  data: {
    token: string;
    user: object;
  };
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  success: false;
  data: {
    error: string;
  };
}

const isSuccessResponse = (res: SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse): res is SuccessResponse => {
  return res.success;
}

const test = (res: SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse) => {
  if (isSuccessResponse(res)) {
    return res.data; // { token: string; user: object; }
  } else {
    return res.data; // { error: string; }
  }
}
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcFIM7YEoTYAOA9iNigN4BQyy2mO2AXMmFOhANy3IAmcMHFY06dMCQDWEEK2ztQAcx5jk6ClFYkARgCsICMCuQBfHierVQkWIhQBRKFBJQCxMhWSj6jQi2TwADYUxgJCIrx00M6a9Aogyrxm1BbUCB5gyMDYGFh+bqTkKAC8yAAUUISsuUwFHigAPsiOMXVFAJSsldhZPTX5hIWexQB8XryVYOhQIMjdAHQMebjmlunkmZDyyKUVVWi+uG2eTS0uxxDtO2PewDDl2f1Hg-V72O1X3nST07MLYXBjCZkBBglRInMIFMZpDsPMAUCUtQgA)